# Getting Single Value From Chunked Array

Tags: php, arrays, session

In an array that is chunked into blocks of 11 values, I need to know if a particular one has a TRUE value. If only one is TRUE, that's all I need and the foreach can stop after it sets a value. All I could think of to do was to make it set a SESSION value to TRUE if a match but that does not stop the loop from continuing and then I had the issue of the SESSION giving false results unless it was then unset which I did after the value was set. Seems rather an indirect way to do it so any suggestions?

```
$FormValues = array_chunk($Fields, $NoValues); // Group together the field values            

// Check if form uses multiple selection fields and add appropriate form tags
    foreach ($FormValues as $multi) :
        if (isset($multi[9]) === TRUE) $_SESSION['useMulti'] = TRUE;
    endforeach;

    $enableMulti = (isset($_SESSION['useMulti'])) ? " enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"" : "";
    unset($_SESSION['useMulti']);
```

Here is an example of an array and, in this case, none should return TRUE:

```
$Fields = array("First Name","Title",$Title,1,0,30,"","","","","",
                "Quote","Quote",$Quote,4,0,30,"","",$quoteSQL,FALSE,$siteDB,
                "Location","Location",$Location,1,0,30,"","","","","",
                "Date","EventDate",$EventDate,41,0,15,"",TRUE,"","","",
                "Time","Time",$Time,39,0,0,"","",$sqlTime,"","",
                );
```

Comment: Why are you using an array like that, instead of a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Why do you need to use a session variable instead of an ordinary variable?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `isset()`.

Comment: I was told by someone else here in a different question that that was a good way to do it and it works. Also, the array may have a different number of elements in each chunk and this lets it be more flexible which is why $NoValues is in a variable. The arrays themselves are generated by yet another form. Anyway, a little too late to change it as it's in use throughout a number of my sites.

Comment: @Barmar What is a better way to do it without getting an error if it does not exist? Without it it sometimes gives errors that the key does not exist, or at least, I expect it might

Comment: @Barmar I don't NEED to use a session value.  I am doing so temporarily simply so I can see what it's doing. My sites' footers have diagnostic code that show POSTS, COOKIES, SESSIONS etc.

Comment: It should be `if (isset($multi[9]) && $multi[9] === TRUE)` to protect against it not being set.

Comment: Your code is just testing whether it's set, not whether it actually has the value `TRUE`.

Comment: Since you unset the variable immediately, you won't see it in the diagnostic code.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, that was an oversight in simplifying the code to post it here. I took out a bit too much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the original array in strides of 11, rather than using `array_chunk`.

To make the loop stop iterating once you've found what you want, use `break`.

You don't need a session variable for this, they're only for preserving values between different PHP scripts. You don't really even need another variable, you can just set the `enableMulti` variable in the loop.

```
$enableMulti = "";
for ($i = 9; i < count($Fields); $i += $NoValues) {
    if ($Fields[$i] === true) {
        $enableMulti = " enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"";
        break;
    }
}
```

If you really want to use `foreach` you do need to use `array_chunk`, and you can also use `array_column`.

```
$enableMulti = "";
$chunks = array_chunk($Fields, $NoValues);
foreach (array_column($chunks, 9) as $value) {
    if ($value === true) {
        $enableMulti = " enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"";
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also get rid of the loop entirely:

```
if array_search(TRUE, array_column($chunks, 9)) {
    $enableMulti = " enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"";
} else {
    $enableMulti = "";
}
```

Comment: Can this be done with foreach instead of for? Not sure why but I seem to grasp foreach better. Anyway, I'll give it a try as it looks like what I was trying to do. As commented above, the session was only for diagnostic purposes and I know it's not needed.

Comment: I've added that.

Comment: It needs $i rather than just i in the for line but with it added to the three places, it seems to work perfectly. As I was writing this, I see you changed it to foreach so thank you!

Comment: Nice to have options and each works perfectly so thanks again! I ended up using the non-looping version as it seemed simpler and more direct.

Comment: You might also consider switching to a more useful data structure to begin with, such as an array of associative arrays.